# How to use globalCompositeOperation in Konva for multiple shapes with scaling

Tags: konvajs

I'm trying to create polygons with an inner border in Konva.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233514/draw-outer-and-inner-border-around-any-canvas-shape/34234589#34234589) example of doing this with `globalCompositeOperation` which works well in Konva, as long as there is only one shape. As soon as I try to add a second shape, this obviously doesn't work anymore and the first shape disappears.

It would work if I were to use a different layer for every shape, but of course that's not a solution that scales well.

I tried using a temporary layer as is done in the example but couldn't get it to work.

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169662/using-globalcompositeoperation-to-mask-group-of-shapes-in-react-konva) example of using `group.cache()`, which works fine ... until I try to scale the stage, at which point I would have to refresh the cache, otherwise I only get the scaled up cache, which looks bad.

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/konva-multilayer-214n1) illustrates the problem. (Please note that this uses simple triangles, in reality I work with arbitray polygons)

So is there a way to use cache with scaling? Or alternatively a better way to use `globalCompositeOperation` with multiple shapes in the same layer? Or some alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: calling `group.cache({pixelRatio: scaleFactor})`. I updated the sandbox.

No idea, if this is the best solution, but it works.